# While doing typings install, throwing error in Angular 4.1.3 version

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I am using Angular 4.1.3 version and using typings 1.4.0 version.
while doing npm install,it throws below error. This was working since yesterday. Since morning, this problem is occring. Any help would be appreciated.

typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/jasmine/tags/2.2.0%2B20160621224255" typings ERR! caused by certificate has expired

typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/core-js/tags/0.0.0%2B20160725163759"
typings ERR! caused by certificate has expired

I have typings.json and below entries

```
"globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
```

I followed below steps but did not work.

- I removed rm -rf node_modules and cache, verify.
- I did npm install typings -g and did npm install

Comment: What happens when you open the problematic links in your browser? Do you also get certificate errors? I don't...

Comment: It is working and giving json object. Not giving certificate errors.

Comment: but still it is giving me above error while doing npm install

Comment: Same problem here. It was working in January and there's an error now. Luckily, I have kept the content of my `typings` directory. So I can keep compiling my typescript files for now. If you have an older copy of your project elsewhere, you can do like me.